# Expanding an Expandablelistview crashes the app

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Following is my getChildView method

```
  @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Following is my getGroupView method

```
 @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.assignee_list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        if (isExpanded) {
            ImageView img_indicator = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.indicator_list);

            img_indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_arrowdown);
        } else {
            ImageView img_indicator = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.indicator_list);
            img_indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_arrow);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Im getting the following error,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setBounds(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at android.widget.ExpandableListView.drawDivider(ExpandableListView.java:537)
                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3313)
                                                                  at android.widget.ExpandableListView.dispatchDraw(ExpandableListView.java:356)
                                                                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15125)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4250)
                                                                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14056)
                                                                  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14079)
                                                                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14846)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
```

Im getting the above error while expanding the expandable listview. How can I be able to sort this out?

Following is my childview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dip"
                android:background="@color/light_color_2"
                android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/chevron"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is my groupview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">


    <TextView
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="assa"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/indicator_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_arrow"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is my expandablelistview xml code

```
  <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:childDivider="@null"
        android:divider="@color/gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"/>
```

Comment: show xml layout, problem is probably here, bc java code looks ok

Comment: you can see group view but you cant see childview means ,there will be mistake in xml file or your declaration in java may be wrong. so post the xml file

Comment: I have included both

Comment: remove this line "android:childDivider="@null""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is in `childDivider`, it shouldn't be null, change it to transparent

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@color/gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"/>
```

Or just delete whole line, it's not required attribute